# Azure Table Storage: "Parameter count mismatch" storing array/list/IEnumerable

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm attempting to write a simple object containing a collection, for example:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<string> GroupIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Using a `DynamicTableEntity` and the `Flatten` method, I'm setting the properties before committing the entity by passing the `UserModel` object as `userModel` as follows:

```
var entity = new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey);
entity.Properties = TableEntity.Flatten(userModel, new OperationContext());
```

This inevitably returns the above mentioned error:

> Parameter count mismatch

From what I can tell, this is due to the 'flatten' method as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/426). I've tried setting my `GroupIDs` object to an array, a List, and IEnumerable with no luck (same issue).

Does anyone have advice for submitting this object with a collection of strings using the flatten method on this type of object in Azure Table Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to share how I solved this one as there isn't much clarity on using `DynamicTableEntity`; at least that I could find easily. If there are other suggestions I'm happy to un-mark this answer.

### Option 1: Concatination

Depending on your requirements, this would be a bad option if the results of concatination exceeded the 64KB limit. I'm certain there are others, however the following method was one option that worked for me. First, I changed the model to reflect a string instead of a list of strings:

```
public List<string> GroupIDs { get; set; } //instead of this

public string GroupIDs { get; set; } //to this
```

I converted my list as follows:

```
var groupList = new List<string>{ "123", "456", "789" };
var userObject = new UserModel(
{
    FirstName = "Jason";
    GroupIDs = string.Join(",", groupList);
});
```

Now the `userObject.GroupIDs` property is a string and can be written as I've shown in the original post.

### Option2: Table Design Modification

I ended up going with this second route as it was easier to store and re-hydrate the object by referencing an ID on the original object. I had to modify the `UserModel` to remove any reference to the groups, then I needed to add a unique ID to it as follows:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I created a table just for the groups to be referenced by the original table. I started by creating a `GroupModel` object to hold the `UserId` I needed to reference:

```
public class GroupModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

I then wrote a new method to handle each object separately as follows:

```
public Interface ITableOps
{
    Task WriteNewUser(UserModel user, List<GroupModel> groups);
}

public class TableOps : ITableOps
{
    public async Task WriteNewUser(UserModel user, List<GroupModel>, groups)
    {
        //...assume user table connection is created

        var entity = new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey);
        entity.Properties = TableEntity.Flatten(user, new OperationContext());
        await userTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(user));

        //...assume group table connection is created

        groups.ForEach(async g =>
            {
                var groupsEntity = new DynamicTableEntity(user.UserId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                groupsEntity.Properties = TableEntity.Flatten(g, new OperationContext());
                await groupsTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(groupsEntity));
            });
    }
```

Lastly, I wrote a simple method to read the entire partition of Groups from the Groups table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `TableEntity.Flatten` in the SDK does not support `ICollection/IEnumerable` type properties. But v2.0 of ObjectFlattener API here supports IEnumerable/ICollection etc. propoerties. https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/

I put some usage example in the Nuget package description, it is very similar to using the `TableEntity.Flatten/ConvertBack` api but with all property types being supported.

Comment: It's very obvious that `Flatten` and `ConvertBack<T>` in the SDK is your code.  Is there a specific reason that the update to 2.0 wasn't included in the SDK?  Also, it's quite difficult to find as it's mostly an undocumented feature except maybe and API reference.

Comment: @AdamVincent Storage SDK team had already stopped taking any further contributions by the time I implemented 2.0 with IEnumerable support. The table storage SDK functionality is ported over to Cosmos DB Table client SDK but they did not open source it.  The general documentation with these api s are same as other api s in the SDK which is generated from XML comments. So not less not more but I certainly agree it is not widely made publicized to developer community considering how powerful the feature is  especially the 2.0 nuget version.

Comment: That's a shame, you can do a lot with KV store but MS gotta push push push that CosmosDB.  Thanks for the response and making `ObjectFlattenerRecomposer` available to us.